# Trying to attach cell formatting (cell color) to information that is being index matched in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors, indexing, match

This is my first time posting, so thanks in advance for any help.

I'm on project and I've come to the last step and I can't seem to figure it out. I essentially creating a employee schedule where when you select a certain shift from a data validation list, it populates the "Shift block" in the row next to it. I have figured out how to bring the data into the row using a Index Match...where I'm getting stuck is that I need the colors associated with the data populating to come with it. This is because I have a count color formula on my master schedule and it is crucial.

Anyone have any ideas on a VBA in excel that could make this happen? I'm really banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: Is the row populated using worksheet functions? or have you used VBA? Could you edit your question to include some examples of any code relating to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to do?

```
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
```

See: [possible colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc296089%28v=office.12%29.aspx#xlDiscoveringColorIndex_ColorIndexProperty)

If it needs to be a certain color based on the selection I would just add that condition to the code.   You could have your new cells color coded onload by doing something like this:

```
If Range("A1").Value = "Night Shift" Then
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If
```